# Jetty 9.4.6 is not sending content type for mp4

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty

I was running Jetty 9.2 and added an explicit mime type which set the content type for mp4 when sending movies back to the client. This worked fine. I then had to upgrade to Jetty 9.4.6 and set AcceptRanges to true so I could get Safari to play mp4. This also works fine. However since applying the upgrade the content type for mp4 is no longer sent back to the client. Why ?

```java
  // Add a handler for statically served content
  ResourceHandler resourceHandler = new ResourceHandler();

  MimeTypes mimeTypes = new MimeTypes();
  mimeTypes.addMimeMapping("mp4", "video/mp4");
  resourceHandler.setMimeTypes(mimeTypes);

  resourceHandler.setAcceptRanges(true);
  resourceHandler.setResourceBase("content");
  handlerCollection.addHandler(resourceHandler);

  // This handle will deal with unhandled requests in the server. For requests for favicon.ico, the Jetty icon is served. 
  // For all other requests a normal 404 is served.
  handlerCollection.addHandler(new DefaultHandler());
```

Filed [Issue #1823](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/1823) eclipse/jetty.project

Comment: Sounds like a possible bug, you should file that at https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues

Comment: Done, bug added at supplied link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jetty guys got back with a workaround, bug will be fixed going forward. The following works

```java
  // Add a handler for statically served content
  ResourceHandler resourceHandler = new ResourceHandler();
  resourceHandler.setAcceptRanges(true);
  resourceHandler.setResourceBase("content");

  // Create a content handler, add the above resource handler and add a mime type for mp4
  ContextHandler context = new ContextHandler("/");
  context.setHandler(resourceHandler);
  MimeTypes mimeTypes = new MimeTypes();
  mimeTypes.addMimeMapping("mp4", "video/mp4");
  context.setMimeTypes(mimeTypes);

  HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
  handlers.addHandler(context);

  // This handle will deal with unhandled requests in the server. For requests for favicon.ico, the Jetty icon is served. 
  // For all other requests a normal 404 is served.
  handlers.addHandler(new DefaultHandler());
```